# Mysql Query Duplication

Tags: mysql

I have this Query:

```
SELECT r.id, r.RowID, r.RAMQ, r.Type, r.Description, r.Deleted
FROM reminders r, patientdetails
WHERE (patientdetails.RAMQ = r.RAMQ OR r.RAMQ='none' )
AND r.Deleted !=  '1'
```

When this Query runs, it duplicates results that have RAMQ none. Why is that?

Comment: You should read abouts joins.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you post some sample data and then the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want data from only one table. So, don't use a join (that's a hidden join you have there) but an `EXISTS` subquery:

```
SELECT  r.id, r.RowID, r.RAMQ, r.Type, r.Description, r.Deleted
FROM    reminders AS r
WHERE   ( r.RAMQ = 'none'
       OR EXISTS
          ( SELECT  *
            FROM    patientdetails AS p
            WHERE   p.RAMQ = r.RAMQ
          )
        )
  AND   r.Deleted <>  '1' ;
```